# Convergence of sum using D'Alembert.

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

I have to find the convergence of this series:
$$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1+{\frac 1n})^n}{2^n}$$
I started by using D'Alembert:
$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$,
So :
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac {\frac{(1+{\frac {1}{n+1}})^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{(1+{\frac {1}{n}})^{n}}{2^{n}}}=$$
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1+{\frac {1}{n+1}})^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}*\frac{2^{n}}{(1+{\frac {1}{n}})^{n}}=$$
I am stuck at this point because I don't really know how to do my simplifications. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: `D'Alembert` with an `e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1+{\frac {1}{n+1}})^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}*\frac{2^{n}}{(1+{\frac {1}{n}})^{n}}=
\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+{\frac{1}{n+1}})^{n+1}}{2^{1}\times(1+{\frac {1}{n}})^{n}}
$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$ (the $+1$ in the numerator doesn't make a difference, as we are dealing with infinity):
$$
=\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{e}{2e}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For $n>1$ you have:
$$0\le\frac{(1+{\frac 1n})^n}{2^n}= \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n 
\le \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n $$